# Add and order elements on page

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like have a bunch of different buttons on the web page. On button toggle (so the button should be pressed down on click and released on second click) the text would be added / removed from a text variable.

So for example, there would be an (at the beginning) empty text and buttons 1, 2, 3, 4

Upon pressing button 1, text should say 1. Then, after pressing 3 and 2, it should say 132. Then, after pressing 1 (again) and 4, it should say 324.

For now, I have this (it just adds number to the string), but how do I toggle the numbers of all the buttons inside of the same string?

```
<p id="textfield"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction('1')">1</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('2')">2</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('3')">3</button>
<button onclick="myFunction('4')">4</button>

<script>
function myFunction(nr) {
    document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML += nr;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "toggle the numbers of all the buttons inside the same string"?

Comment: Check if the number is already in the string. If it is in the string remove it, if not add it to the string.

Comment: you may find this useful: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following code should do the trick for you.

```
<script>
function myFunction(nr) {
   var str = document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML;
   if(str.indexOf(nr) >=0)
   str = str.replace(nr,"");
   else
   str += nr;

    document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML = str;
}
</script>
```

Please check the **[Fiddle with working example](https://jsfiddle.net/6f9959d9/17/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
 var nums=[];  
 function myFunction(nr)
  var pos=nums.findIndex(el=>el==nr);
  if(pos>-1)(
   //exist so remove
    nums.splice(pos,1);
  }else{
   //append at the end
    nums.push(nr);
  }
  //add to html:
  document.getElementById("textfield").innerHTML=nums.join("");
  }
```